# How to connect to a IPv6 service using IPv4 connection on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, networking, tcp, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to work out how to connect an inbound IPv4 connection to a port listening on a IPv6 port on a CentOS box.

To demonstrate on a vanilla CentOS 7 server:

1. Confirm `bindV6only` is disabled

```
   $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only
   0
```

2. Run netcat listening on a IPv6 port

```
   nc -lvn6p 80
```

3. On another shell, attempt to telnet to the port via IPv4

```
   telnet 127.0.0.1 80
```

*Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused*

### Further information

- Trying to connect via IPv6 works as expected. e.g. telnet ::1 80
- However everything I'm reading suggests that Linux-based IPv6 sockets should accept IPv4 connections too if net.ipv6.bindv6only is disabled in sysctl, which it is.
- I've tried Socket CAT, it works but isn't an elegant solution and requires a separate service to be configured. e.g.

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork TCP6:[::1]:80
```

ref: https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/ipv6/bindv6only/

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343747/ipv6-socket-creation

Comment: ::1 isn't an IPv4-mapped address.  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57903/are-the-ipv6-address-space-and-ipv4-address-space-completely-disjoint/

Comment: It's interesting the ::1 isn't IPv4 mapped. This is likely the core issue with my above example. I'll try a remote connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem, but running `yum install nc` on centos 7 will install `nmap-ncat`, which does set the `SOL_IPV6/IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option itself on ipv6 sockets:

```
# strace -e trace=setsockopt nc -lvn6p 80
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, [1], 4) = 0
Ncat: Listening on :::80
```

If you omit the `-6` and `-4` options, it will bind two different `ipv6` and `ipv4` sockets:

```
# strace -e trace=bind,setsockopt nc -lvnp 80
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(80), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
Ncat: Listening on :::80
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:80
```

Apparently, the `nmap` people aren't great fans of the dual-stack sockets feature of Linux ;-)